# Accumulation Variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a table, each row consists of 7 columns, and in the form of 5 cells:

```
 <ROW>
   <CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">1</CELL>
   <CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">Mandrel</CELL>
   <CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">1</CELL>
   <CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="2">H079249303</CELL>
   <CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="2">H079249301</CELL>
 </ROW>
```

Now my template match against each individual `<CELL>` and turn them into `<entry>`, and for those with a `@COLSPAN` value greater than 1 (like the last two cells above), I need to have a `namest` and `namend` attribute for them, so for example, the above code will turn into:

```
  <row>
    <entry>1</entry>
    <entry>Mandrel</entry>
    <entry>1</entry>
    <entry namest="c4" nameend="c5">H079249303</entry>
    <entry namest="c6" nameend="c7">H079249301</entry>
  </row>
```

I am able to keep track of the number of preceding siblings, but really have no idea of how to sum the `@COLSPAN` attribute of all preceding siblings since XSLT doesn't allow variable increment.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe last `entry` has `namest="c5"`?

Comment: I guess that this is about generating a CALS table, where `namest` = name of the leftmost column in a column span and `nameend` = name of the rightmost column in the span. The column names are supposed to be defined in a `<colspec>` element.

Comment: @mzjn, you are 100% correct. So the last two cells should occupy two columns each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `sum` function, i.e.:

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <row>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CELL"/>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CELL">
    <entry>
      <xsl:if test="@COLSPAN > 1">
        <xsl:attribute name="namest">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('c', sum(preceding-sibling::CELL/@COLSPAN) + 1)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="nameend">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('c', sum(preceding-sibling::CELL/@COLSPAN) + @COLSPAN)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**:

```
<row>
  <entry>1</entry>
  <entry>Mandrel</entry>
  <entry>1</entry>
  <entry namest="c4" nameend="c5">H079249303</entry>
  <entry namest="c6" nameend="c7">H079249301</entry>
</row>
```

Comment: thanks. But I think the last entry should be from c6 to c7 instead of c5.

Comment: There are 7 columns for a row. The first three cells occupy 1 cell only, while the later two should occupy two columns. So the fourth cell should start from c4 and end in c5(two columns), while the last cell should start from c6 and end in c7(two columns). Hope that helps